# View Android keyboard cache

Tags: android, caching

I'm trying to do vulnerability assessment on Android devices. 
I'd like to know if , with root permission, there's a way to view all the words saved in the cache of the Android keyboard (all the word that are suggested while typing).

Comment: Presumably. With root, you can do lots of things. However, given root privileges, an app can do a lot worse to the user than peek at keyboard suggestions. If you are considering "able to get root and then peek at keyboard suggestions" to be a vulnerability, you can just stop at "able to get root", IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the advice,i know that. Anyway I'de like to know where the cache is stored and if is encrypted or not

Comment: I am trying to find a way as well for this issue. I am looking for something similar to iOS keyboard caching security issue where there are known binary signatures in the app that the security tester can look for in a dumped binary like setAutocorrectionType: and UITextField. In iOS app binaries, if setAutocorrectionType: is present and UITextField is absent, then we flag it as a security issue/vulnerability. Does anyone have any clue to do the somehow similar thing in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Google's Gboard app, the path is **/data/data/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/files/cache** . Files here in .dict and .acc format exists containing the data of typing of respective languages, one is using with the app.
One will need root access to go to that path and open the files.

Comment: Thanks, it may help. But i need to work on the cache of default keyboard

Comment: Default AOSP keyboard is in /data/data/packagename . Try using it. Welcome. Consider a upvote. :)

Comment: yeah but what's the package name ?

Comment: com.android.inputmethodcommon

Comment: Found it under  **com.sec.android.inputmethod** on Android 4.3. Thank you!